# Python 3.4.1 don't show the result?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I think the code is right, but don't show the final, any error appears

I was trying to do a program that could put both population and rates freely, and I could repeat.

```
hab_A = 0
hab_B = 0
tax_A = 0
tax_B = 0

while hab_A < 1:
  hab_A = int(input('population country A '))

while hab_B < 1:
  hab_B = int(input('population country B '))

while tax_A <= 0:
  tax_A = float(input('growth rates population country A '))

while tax_B <= 0:
  tax_B = float(input('growth rates population country B '))

anos = 0
while hab_A < hab_B:
  anos  += 1
  hab_A += ((hab_A*tax_A/100))
  hab_B +=((hab_B*tax_B/100))

print('The population of the country A will exceed the country B in: ')
print('population country A : ',(hab_A) )
print('population country B : ' ,(hab_B) )
```

Comment: Please do post your code **here**, and not on ideone.

Comment: The error on ideone appears because you need to specify the stdin input up front. No such error would appear if you ran this *on your own computer instead*.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - Hi I don't know how ... put the code here T.T

Comment: @MartijnPieters I suggest a rollback because in the apparently appropriate edit, we removed the source of the problem.

Comment: @ZenOfPython: Apparently I did. But then it is a question about ideone, which is a web service, and the question is not nearly so on topic.

Comment: @ZenOfPython: besides, we have a specific off-topic reason for questions such as these: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.* No errors are present here, and no explanation that the code was only tried on ideone.

Comment: hum ... sorry, I guess I didn't understand well T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran this on [ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com), and the code did not ask for input because **because you need to specify the stdin input up front**. Instead, try this on a working computer, and it shall work perfectly fine.

[ideone.com:](http://www.ideone.com)

> [image]stdin copy
>
> ---
>
> Standard input is empty

Working Computer:

```
bash-3.2$ python3.4 test.py
population country A 10
population country B 5
growth rates population country A 1
growth rates population country B 2
The population of the country A will exceed the country B in: 
population country A :  10
population country B :  5
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: really sorry for the incovenience, I only put the ideone for show my code consider the first part, the part where has the compilation is not considered ... and try edited, but no appear the result